# how to disable all columns apart from one column in Qtablewidget PYQT - python

Tags: python, pyqt4

Problem Statement:
Disable specific columns and enable specific row on bases of current row index.

I am working on Qtablewidget i tried following code this working fine for disable.
i wanted to enable tablewidget row contents on bases of row index .
when i  clicked pushbutton that row should be enable.I am new to the stackoverflow please guide me.I am tring to enable tablewidget cell,pushbutton,combobox i am not getting please guide me how to enble particular row on bases of index.

Code :

```
self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
myresult = [(u'sandeep', u'checkbox'), (u'shivaraj', u'checkbox')]

for row, result in enumerate(myresult):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
        for column, value in enumerate(result):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
            if column == 1:
                if (value == "textbox"):
                    self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox()

                    lis = ("---select---", "description", "multiple_input")
                    self.cb.addItems(lis)
                    self.cb.setCurrentIndex(1)
                    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, self.cb)
                    self.cb.setEnabled(False)#this is for combobox disable
                elif (value == "checkbox"):
                    self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox()

                    lis = ("---select---", "description", "multiple_input")
                    self.cb.addItems(lis)
                    self.cb.setCurrentIndex(2)
                    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, self.cb)
                    self.cb.setEnabled(False)#this is for combobox disable


            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
            item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)#this is for text non editable

            self.btn_sell = QtGui.QPushButton('Edit')

            self.btn_sell1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Delete')
            self.btn_sell1.setEnabled(False)#this for button disble

            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, self.btn_sell)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, self.btn_sell1)
            self.btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.edit)        
 def edit(self):
   index = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
   print index
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have asked for something, if you want help then provide what I have asked

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...i am working on a Table Widget, i am implementing EDIT option so that i can allow user to Edit specific ROWS, to implement EDIT option, i followed 2 steps :       .
1 ) Disable all columns except EDIT button column, 
2 ) Enable specific ROWS based the EDIT button clicked ROW.  So that only specific ROWs are Enabled and user is able to update Edit button pressed row contents. 

i am failed to enable table cell widgets.combobox,pushbuttons

Comment: You do not get tired of explaining to me, the main thing is that you provide an MCVE for me to test it and know where the problem is, I do not want to invest my time (which is also valuable) in guessing in which part of your code has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
    self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 100, 881, 100))
    self.table.setColumnCount(4)
    self.table.setRowCount(1)  

    self.table.setColumnWidth(0, 120)
    self.table.setColumnWidth(1, 500)
    self.table.setColumnWidth(2, 120)
    self.table.setColumnWidth(3, 120)

    indexes = self.tableWidget.currentRow()

     widget = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(indexes, 2)
        # print widget

     if isinstance(widget, QtGui.QComboBox):
          h = str(widget.currentText())

          if (h == "multiple_input"):
               j = "checkbox"
          elif (h == "description"):
                j = "textbox"

    if (j == "textbox"):
                self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox()
                lis = ("---select---", "description", "multiple_input")
                self.cb.addItems(lis)
                self.cb.setCurrentIndex(1)
                self.table.setCellWidget(0, 2, self.cb)

    [enter image description here][1]elif (j == "checkbox"):
                self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox()
                lis = ("---select---", "description", "multiple_input")
                self.cb.addItems(lis)
                self.cb.setCurrentIndex(2)
                self.table.setCellWidget(0, 2, self.cb)     


    n = [str(self.tableWidget.item(indexes, 0).text())]
    for x in n:
        f = ''.join(map(str, x))
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(f))



    n1 = [str(self.tableWidget.item(indexes, 1).text())]
    # print n1
    for i in n1:
        s = ''.join(i)
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(s))

    self.li = QtGui.QPushButton("Update")

    self.table.setCellWidget(0, 3, self.li)
    self.li.clicked.connect(self.edit_data)

    self.table.show()
```

click on  below link has image.

[image: Edit values in separate table]

Try the above code:

Select row and click on edit button it will take the current index row values into the separate table `where we can edit and update the values.This is the one way i have tried  to update the value it works fine.

Comment: I find it strange that you and the OP have questions with very similar code, is there any reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: @Sandeep - thanks for the Response, I am aware of this alternative method, is there any way to Enable directly in function by passing the row index.

Comment: @eyllanesc -I have shared the updated code 2nd time after editing.my problem is solved with alternative method. can you please suggest or share prefered tutorials link for the pyqt4 programming

Comment: @AbhilashPujari I have never used a PyQt tutorial, I initially learned Qt (C ++) and then as I know python the transition was simple.

Comment: @eyllanesc - ok, i am PYQT4 learning from online tutorials,blogs etc..facing problems in syntax,fundamentals, getting help from stackoverflow a lot and i am very thinkfull to your Quick response for other questions i posted, thank you very much, i am  new to stackoverflow ,learning how to post questions, my appologies if the questions posted formats are not proper, i am correcting them, thank you .

Comment: @AbhilashPujari f you know well python, and especially OOP then you only need to review the docs, try examples and look in the SO questions/answers